# Android grid layout with circular item in random position

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I am trying to implement different grid layout structure but unfortunately not getting success. So please look on below screenshot and tell me is it possible to implement gridview or recyclerview like below screenshot. Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: You could try using 3 recycleviews

Comment: That's not really random. Is  it possible to draw a vertical line between two columns of images?

Comment: I think you can use StaggeredGridLayoutManager in recyclerview

Answer (score 3):

Use `GridLayoutManager` with `spancount` 3

Now set the custom top margin to your root layout for the second position.

Apply this logic to your RecyclerViewAdapter's `onBindViewHolder`

```
if (position % 3 == 1) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            relativeParams.setMargins(0, 50, 0, 0);  // left, top, right, bottom
            holder.rel_root.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
   }
```

not sure if it's correct way but works :)

[image: output]